# Why does injectivity imply to $|G/(H \cap K)|\leq |G/H|\cdot|G/K|?$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I'm looking through some proof about the inequality in the title, the one defines:

$$\phi: G/(H \cap K)\rightarrow G/H\times G/K$$

$$\phi(g(H \cap K))=(gH,gK)$$

Note that $\phi$ is injective, I'd like to know why the such injectivity implies that:

$$\left|G/(H \cap K)\right| \leq |G/H|\cdot|G/K|$$

I have no idea, you don't need to prove just getting a useful idea to answering this is enough.

Comment: If $S$ and $T$ are finite sets and $f: S \to T$ is an injective function, do you see why $|S| \leq |T|$?

Comment: @Daniel, I guess no, because this is precisely what the OP is asking.

Comment: Search for "pigeonhole principle".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by induction regarding injections and part of the pigeonhole principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228581/proof-by-induction-regarding-injections-and-part-of-the-pigeonhole-principle)

Comment: I think robert's answer was enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\left \vert \frac GH \times \frac GK \right \vert = \left \vert \frac GH \right \vert \cdot \left \vert \frac GK \right \vert$.  Since $\phi$ is injective, every element of $\frac {G}{H \cap K}$ maps to a unique ordered pair in the cross product $\frac GH \times \frac GK$ (possibly with some ordered pairs in the cross product left over).  This proves the desired inequality because you can't injectively map a set into a smaller set.